# Is it safe to keep a callback listener in Activity like Dialog?

Tags: java, android

we know that, Dialog can hold a callback listener like OnCancelListener, when the dialog is canceled
 the method of listener get callback. I want to know is it safe to keep a listener in Activity,just like the Dialog. For that, I can get callback when the Activity finish.

If it's not safe to do this, why?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What resources have you read already?

Comment: @stkent what's your mean?

Answer (score 0):

You Need onActivityResult() that is you need result from an activity you can use startActivity for result. refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for more info.